# How does Android flip the Home Screens?

Tags: android

I've implemented an adapterViewFlipper in my application but the way it flips the views, with the 'onFling' event calling displayNext(previous)Picture() is not so cool because the scrolling acts automatically AFTER your gesture is ended.

I would like to know how to implement flipping like Android does with the Home screens where the view follows your finger.

Any idea?

Comment: you mean you need to change views on swiping the screen.if so please use viewpager.

Comment: View Pager Is for that Purpose, what u are asking for , But u got only scroll kind of animation on that while with View flipper u can use your own custom animation to flip a View. For More Look Here: http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/scroll.html

Comment: Ok, thanks and like I can see here, http://androidopentutorials.com/android-image-slideshow-using-viewpager/, viewPager can also be use to swipe views in a screen.